# get MySql Data to PHP array and convert to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I have mysql table like this

table = tbl_tst`

`clm_num   clm_amnt`

`1      -  25000`
`2      -  31700`
`5      -  52900`
`8      -  45000`

I want to get that table data to php array like this

`$temp = array([1,25000],[2,31700],[5,52900],[8,45000]);`

After i'll convert php array into the javascript using this code

`var jsArray = <? echo json_encode($temp); ?>;`

#### Problem is when i run my code it's retrieve nothing. sometimes it's retrieving "Object" :(

This is my full php code

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("db", $con); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblnum"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$valueMap = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $valueMap[$row['clm_num'] & $row['clm_amnt']];
}
?>

<script>
var jsArray = <? echo json_encode($valueMap); ?>;
for(var i=0; i < jsArray .length; i++){
document.write("<li>"+jsArray [i]+"</li>");
}
</script>
```

Please help me to find this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try writing your javascript code inside document load event as below.  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      .. here..
   }
 }

Comment: You probably meant to write `$valueMap[$row['clm_num']] = $row['clm_amnt']];` instead of `$valueMap[$row['clm_num'] & $row['clm_amnt']];`

Answer (score 2):

You should enable PHP displaying errors, which would tell you there is an error while constructing your array.

```
<?php
 ## Turn on error reporting
 error_reporting(-1);
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
 ....
 $valueMap = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $valueMap[$row['clm_num']] = $row['clm_amnt'];
 }
?>
```

edit:

You requested a different sort of array I see:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $valueMap[] = array($row['clm_num'], $row['clm_amnt']);
}
```

MySQL is no longer maintained, please start using MySQLI or PDO http://rudiv.se/Development/Resource/when-to-use-mysql-vs-mysqli-vs-pdo-in-php

edit:

```
<?php

$temp = array(
    array(1,2500),  
    array(2,31700)
);

?>

<ul id="list"></ul>

<script>

    var json_array = <?php echo json_encode($temp, true);?>;    

    console.log(json_array);    

    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    for(i in json_array){       
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json_array[i][0]+','+json_array[i][1])); 
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: i changed code line to `$valueMap[$row['clm_num']] = $row['clm_amnt'];` but nothing happened :( it's retrieve nothing.

Comment: Lets do it step by step, directly after the while loop, on the next line: echo "<pre>".print_r($valueMap, true)."<pre>"; and excute to see  it the php array is generated.

Comment: yeah it's fine. it's working perfectly in php. but problem is i need to get that data array like this `$temp = array([1,25000],[2,31700],[5,52900],[8,45000]);` in javascript

Comment: just updated the answer, though it would help if you could show what the desired html output would be.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check your php array is come or not. if it will be coming than use this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var js_data = <?php echo json_encode($valueMap); ?>;
  var jsArray = js_data.toString().split(',');
  for(var i=0; i < jsArray.length; i++){
    alert(jsArray[i]);
  }
</script>
```

This one for one array or one dimensional array like array['amount']. 
i used this code for

```
$valueMap = array('25000','31700','52900','45000'); // php array
```

check this.

Answer (score 0):

change this  `$valueMap[$row['clm_num'] & $row['clm_amnt']];` To  `$valueMap[] =array($row['clm_num'], $row['clm_amnt']);`

```
    $valueMap = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $valueMap[] =array($row['clm_num'], $row['clm_amnt']);
    }
    ?>

<script>
var jsArray = <?php echo json_encode($temp); ?>;//change <? to <?php  it's give error when sort tag is not enable 
for(var i=0; i < jsArray .length; i++){
document.write("<li>"+jsArray [i]+"</li>");
}
</script>
```

//output

```
1,25000
2,31700
5,52900
8,45000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $valueMap[$row['clm_num']] = $row['clm_amnt'];
}
```

And then in js:

```
for(var i in jsArray){
    if (jsArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        document.write("<li>"+jsArray[i]+"</li>");
    }
}
```